# Regular Expression for Simple Arithmetic String

Tags: java, regex, math

I'm trying to validate a simple arithmetic expression to insure it fits within the format operand operator operand : 234.34 + 5.  I figured out how to validate this easy enough, but I want the users to be able to continue inputting more than 2 values such as: 234.34 + 5 / 6 * 7 - -34.  So far my regex is as follows:

```
[-]*\d+[.\d+[E\d+]*]*[\s+[*+/-]\s+[-]*\d+[.\d+[E\d+]*]*]*
```

This partially works, but the problem I have is it allows for some strange things I don't want such as -4.34.1 - 34 +

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take your exist regex that worked for 234.34 + 5, then just tweak it so you have something like (operand)+((operator)(operand))*

Comment: I do not think you should use a regex for this necessarily.  Why not use a stack and push and pop on operands.

Comment: The language of infix arithmetic operations is a typical example of context-free languages. If you want anything more than just validating, you're better off with a context-free parser.

Comment: Michael, I'm actually splitting this string and building a binary tree from it.  I was mostly using this for validation before bothering to parse.  Not the best way to go, I can see now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. It's ugly as hell but it should work (if you aren't using any parentheses):

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E\d+)?)?(\s*[-+/\*]\s+-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E\d+)?)?)+
```

Explanation

This will math a number followed by an operator and a number indefinitely

- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E\d+)?)?` Match a number
- `(`

  - `\s*` optional whitespace
  - `[-+/\*]` any operator: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`
  - `\s+` at least one whitespace (to avoid a --b)
  - `-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E\d+)?)?` match another number
- `)+` repeat this block one or more times

And the number expression:

- `-?` optional `-`
- `\d+` digits (one or more)
- `(?:` start of optional part

  - `\.` dot
  - `\d+` digits
  - `(?:` start of optional scientific notation part

    - E match `E` char
    - `\d+` match digitx
  - `)?` close of the optional scientific notatotion part
- `)?` close optional group

But i strongly suggest trying to write a proper parser for this, it will also allow supporting of parentheses: `a + (b + c)`.

Comment: wow... nice! but it doesn't do 5 -.5, u'd have to put 5 - 0.5, not sure if that's a concern..

Comment: Yea :(. It depends on how strict he wants the parsing to be. It can be done :). But a parser is usually better :).

Comment: It could definitely use a parser, but this became more of a question of CAN it be done.  I agree this isn't optimal, but it became more of a learning situation in case some other need arises where I need optional repeating validation.

Comment: I'm seeing now what I suspected all along, which is I was misusing the regex class [] characters.  This really answered my question, thanks Toader.  It's hard to know WHEN to use a parser versus just validating with Regex.

Comment: A lot of things influence this: do you need semantics? can you write it fast and correctly (the regex)?, how complex is the re ?, is the language regular or not ? it's a one time job or not ? etc.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to be "that guy" but why not just write a simple validator that parses the string without using regular expressions?  What's the reasoning behind using regular expressions for this?  If you were to write your own parser, not only will the solution be easier to understand and maintain but with a little bit more work you would be able to evaluate the expression as well.

Comment: +1 - for being that guy.  It should also be noted that the regex approach will fail if he adds parenthesis to his (umm) grammar.

Comment: Care to discuss the difference between "parsing" and matching with regex?

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to just write a parser. I know, that sounds scary, but this is actually a second-year homework exercise at college.

See Dijkstra's [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). This will allow you to both verify and evaluate the expression, so if that is where you're going with this project, **you're going to have to implement it anyways**...

Answer (score 1):

i released an expression evaluator based on [Dijkstra's Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, under the terms of the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string.split to get each operand and value by itself. Then you can parse it using much simpler regex `([\d*.\d*|\d|+|-|*|/])` or just `Integer.getInterger` for your values.