# javascript Regular expression for validating arithmetic expression

Tags: javascript

I have an arithmetic expression
((20+30)-25)/5
 I want to validate by using regular expression. The expression can only have integers, floating point numbers, operands and parenthesis.

How can I generate regular expression to validate please help or suggest any other way to validate that string using javascript.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085524/regular-expression-for-simple-arithmetic-string Regex is the same throughout most languages.

Comment: What have you tried ? The following link should help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @Derek: Misleading, even if you said "most". This is not possible by preg engine or standard regular expressions (as they can't balance parentheses), but doable using Oniguruma (available in Ruby and some others, but not JavaScript)

Comment: this is impossible to parse using regular expressions. you need to use a context free grammar.

Comment: @akonsu why CFG? can give a little brief

Comment: because the expressions in the original post have parentheses. regular expressions cannot count parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, this is impossible using one JavaScript regular expression. However, you can do it using a loop: replace subexpressions with atoms, repeat until you get an atom. If you can't reduce any more, and whatever is left is not an atom, it does not validate. This is actually pretty much the same procedure you'd do to evaluate it (just skipping the abstract syntax tree). You can search for `\(\d+\)|\d+[-+/*]\d+` and replace with `0`:

Example:

- `((20+30)-25)/5`
- `((0)-25)/5`
- `(0-25)/5`
- `(0)/5`
- `0/5`
- `0`
- Done

If you failed to match and didn't have just `0`, it's a fail.

(To evaluate as opposed to validate, you'd just have to be replacing with with the actual value rather than a dummy stand-in, everything else is the same).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript "eval" function is the best validator.
Try to do this:

```
eval("((20+30)-25)5");
```

and you will get sufficiently detailed error description.

Comment: But `eval` input string must be properly sanitized before execution with it.

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to do this with regular expressions if you impose a maximum depth to the parenthesis nesting. Otherwise, the set of arithmetic expressions forms a context free language but not a regular language.

If I had to use regex, the approach I would use is to write a regular grammar for your set of arithmetic expressions and then convert that to a regular expression.

Another approach is to write a recursive descent parser, which is a fairly simple project and works very nicely for arithmetic expressions.